# Android Query regarding phone-book

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am working on my application related to sms sending.When i am fetching contacts from the phone-book in my application, its showing me the duplicate contacts like contact "Bhan" have two saved numbers i.e 2222 and 3333 . When i am viewing it from application, its showing me two different contacts,one with number 2222 and other with 3333 . I am running my app in emulator.Is it some kind of setting in emulator only or do i have to some different coding for this.I am using this code.

```
public int REQUESTCODE = 1;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
/ defining button elements for picking contacts from phone-book
        btn_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpickperson);
        btn_cntct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // using Intent for fetching contacts from phone-book
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Isn't this normal behavior? Application must ask where should send sms..

Comment: if a single contact name is having multi contact number, it shows a single contact name only(when u send msg from msg box). not same name for different numbers but its showing me for my app :(

Comment: :D Go to Messaging app, try to compose... add recipients then picture will be clear when you select a contact which having multiple number..

Comment: oky ,,, so if i have a contact name with 10 numbers saved, it will show me 10 contacts from messanging app ??

Comment: is there is any way , it will show only 1 contact name and when i choose that , a dialog will appear with all the numbers of that contact on it along with a check box to choose from

Comment: Actually it depends on manufacturer. This app behaves different for same. Like you are able to see names instead of numbers, but in my device it shows numbers of the contact. So I think better option is to implement UI to show all contacts and show all numbers into list if contact having multiple number, and then call sms related stuffs using selected number

Comment: so, if my boss is forcing to do something like this , what shall i say to him

Comment: okay , just tell me, if its possible , like i have two edittext views for fetching contacts from phone-book and when i choose contact for first edittext view , i don't want that same contact to be visible for the second one . Is it possible